# Setting up fields and constructors using ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, constructor, field

I think i've almost got it right, i've had a look through some documentation but nothing is quite helping me...
This is what I have so far:

```
    // data field
    private ArrayList students;

    // constructor
    public students(What goes here?) {
        this.students = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

How do I finish this off?

Comment: A read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) won't hurt, but the real question is, what is it you expect to happen?  How do you want it to work? Because the answer to *"What goes here?*" is *"What ever you want"*....

Comment: *"How do I finish this off?"* What is *this*?

Comment: I'm setting up an arraylist that I can add students names to...

Answer (score 1):

If you want your constructor to accept list of students and copy reference to it then your code can look like

```
// data field
private ArrayList students;

// constructor
public students(ArrayList<String> students) {
    this.students = students;
}
```

But in case you don't want to take list in constructor then don't take anything as argument and in constructors create your own empty list of students

```
// constructor
public students() {
    this.students = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: @user2849489 Make sure your class is named `students`, or even better `Students` and in that case change your constructor to `public Students(...`

Answer (score 0):

You probably wouldn't put anything there, if that's all your code...

Answer (score 0):

**Make your class name exactly equal to you constructer name. I am assuming you class name as Student. (Capital `S`)**

You  can write your constructer in several ways:

```
public Students() {
    this.students = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And if you are passing a array list reference than it's better to consider **defensively copy** of individual object of the array rather than directly assinging the reference to your class variable. You read more [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2).